# Is there an way to get basic "spell completion" with an .dic file in PhpStorm?

Tags: dictionary, phpstorm, code-completion, spelling

Is there an way to get basic "spell completion" with an .dic file in PhpStorm ?

I think it's possible because on [this page](http://blog.novoj.net/2010/11/07/how-to-add-your-own-dictionary-to-intellij-idea-spellchecker/) we can find [this image](http://blog.novoj.net/binary/2010/11/dictionary-after.png)

But I've just installed a dictionary now. It's work, but it's say only if it's wrong or right.

My currently version of PhpStorm is 8.0.3.

Comment: Code completion with dictionary ?? No. Dictionaries are for spell checking only. Although in comments it's sometimes possible to complete plain words (not sure how it actually works TBH)

Comment: Yeah but have you see [this image](http://blog.novoj.net/binary/2010/11/dictionary-after.png) ? Yeah, it's on an other product of intelliJ...but it also have to work on PhpStorm.

Comment: Of course I've seen the image. And that is NOT code completion -- that's spell checker -- it offers you alternatives of what it thinks is misspelled word.

Comment: Here you go: http://postimg.org/image/f36zj7kg5/

Comment: how do you do that ? That exactly what I searched.

Comment: You will not believe ... but it's `Alt+Enter` (just as your image suggests) .. or the same via Right click on misspelled word: http://postimg.org/image/idtozyxxr/

Comment: It's right ! How can I do for don't see that ! Thank :D But Is there a shortcut key for get this directly. (not alt+enter -> enter) ^_^ But if you don't find, no problem. alt+enter is not horrible... I can survive ^^

Comment: Custom shortcut is not possible -- Spell checker menu is implemented via mechanism of Intentions .. which does not allow assigning shortcuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spell checker suggestions (from dictionaries on misspelled words) can be reached by:

- via Quick Fix menu (invoked by <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>) while standing on word highlighted by Typo inspection

[image]

- via Context Menu (right click) on such misspelled (or unknown to IDE) word

[image]

---

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/spellchecking.html?search=spell